# Problems with r betadisper

Tags: r

I am trying to use the betadisper function from vegan package in R to look at the similarity of two insect communities in urban and suburban sites. But every time I try to use it it gives me this.

```
Error in pts[groups == i, , drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

When I trace back it says traceback()

```
3: ordimedian(vectors, group, choices = axes[pos])
2: spatialMed(vectors, group, pos)
1: betadisper(dist[[3]], groups)
```

This is my script.

```
install.packages("betapart")`
install.packages("vegan")
library(betapart)
library(vegan)
comm <- read.csv("Hym div3.csv")
groups <- factor(c(rep(1,8), rep(9,11)), labels = c("Suburban","Urban"))
presabs<-ifelse(comm>0,1,0)
dist<-beta.pair(presabs, index.family="jaccard")
bd<-betadisper(dist[[3]],groups)
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Could you share in your post the output of `dput(comm)` ?

Comment: And a sample of the "Hym div3.csv" file as well?